# node.js: Cannot read property 'defaultEncoding' of undefined

Tags: node.js, process, stdout

I wanted to write a changeable write() function.

```
var write = function(s) {
    process.stdout.write(s);
}
write("Hello world!");
```

I thought you could just write it shorter:

```
var write = process.stdout.write;
write("Hello world!");
```

But here I will receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultEncoding' of undefined
    at Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:172:21)
    at Socket.write (net.js:613:40)
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all has to do with how javascript handles `this`. Inside the function `process.stdout.write` [there is a call](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/_stream_writable.js#L210) to `defaultEncoding()` using `this` variable.

In javascript, `this` is not assigned a value until an object invokes the function where this is defined and it is relative to the calling object.

So in your first example, `this` points to `process.stdout` object and it has the method `defaultEncoding`.
In your second example, `this` is `undefined` since the function is being called from the global namespace. When `process.stdout.write` tries to call `defaultEncoding`, it will throw the error you mentioned.

You can manually define the `this` value for a function using [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method. Example:

```
var write = process.stdout.write;
write.call(process.stdout, "Hello world!");
```

The first argument of `call` is the object to be used as `this` inside the function.

I recommend reading [this article](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/), it explains a lot about `this` in javascript.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `.bind()` method, it is designed exactly for your case.

```
var write = process.stdout.write.bind(process.stdout);
write("Hello world!");
```

This sets `this` variable inside the `process.stdout.write` method to `process.stdout`.